# How to Pass object to REST Get Method

Tags: rest, jersey

I am using Jersey Rest implementation. There are one Rest Services Called HelloWorld. See the below code. 
Please consider this code as reference not as compiled code.

```
@Path("helloWorld")
public class HelloWorld{

  @Path("test")
  @Produces(...)
  @Consum(...)
  @GET
  public Response test(Person person){
    System.out.println(person);
  }
}
```

I am using Jersey client to sent the request.
Here My question is apart from POST method is there any way to send the object to GET method directly. Instead of QueryString.

Please let me if there is any way to do so.

Thanks

Comment: It's probably possible. But what's the motivation?

Comment: Motivation is, ideally we should use the Get method to fetch the data from database. So if we have lots of param to pass with escape character then I think it would be good idea to sent the object directly instead of param.

Comment: Is It not working? Are you getting some errors/warnings? What client are you using? What server are you using? Some clients/servers will prevent this, but sometimes have switches you can flip to allow it.

Comment: Could you please send me any sample or example over net so that I can see it. I am using weblogic server to deploy the Rest Service and Jersey on both Services and client implementation.

Comment: It is Jersey 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: Its Jersey 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem shouldn't be with the server. I did a few tests on different servers (not weblogic as I don't use it) and all of them seem to have no problems accepting a body in the GET request. The problem seem to be with the client. To test I used the following code

```
ClientBuilder.newClient()
        .target("http://localhost:8080/api/get-body")
        .property(ClientProperties.SUPPRESS_HTTP_COMPLIANCE_VALIDATION, true)
        .request()
        .method(HttpMethod.GET, Entity.text("Hello World"));
```

The `SUPPRESS_HTTP_COMPLIANCE_VALIDATION` allows us to pass a body to the request. If we didn't use this, then we would get an error.

The problem with this code, is that even though we set this override property, the client completely overrides the `GET` method and automatically makes it a `POST` method, so I would get back a 405 Method Not Allowed.

The solution I came up with is to just allow the client to set a header, e.g. `X-GET-BODY-OVERRIDE`, and then use a `@PreMatching` filter on the server side to check for this header. If the header is present, then just change the method to a `GET`

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class GetWithBodyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
        String getOverride = request.getHeaderString("X-GET-BODY-OVERRIDE");
        if (getOverride != null && "true".equalsIgnoreCase(getOverride)) {
            request.setMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
        }
    }
}
```

Then just register the filter with the server side. On the client, you would simply need to add the header

```
ClientBuilder.newClient()
        .target("http://localhost:8080/api/get-body")
        .property(ClientProperties.SUPPRESS_HTTP_COMPLIANCE_VALIDATION, true)
        .request()
        .header("X-GET-BODY-OVERRIDE", "True")
        .method(HttpMethod.GET, Entity.text("Hello World"));
```

This solution is good because it takes into account more than just the Jersey client, in regards with being able to send a body in the GET request.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try this one.